# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x(1-x)^{n-1}$ Does this sum converge uniformly?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x(1-x)^{n-1}$$

I know that this sum converge $\iff$ $0\le x \le 1$, i wanted to use the Weierstrass but could not suceed, so i think this sum might not converge uniformly,but i'm having problem showing it.

Comment: Compute the partial sums explicitly. It is a geometric sum.

Comment: Note the following two facts: (1) the summands are continuous functions, (2) the limit is *not* continuous on $[0, 1]$. (*Hint.* you can compute the limit explicitly. See Kavi Rama Murthy's comment.). What can you say from these?

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but this one cannot be tested by Weierstrass M test.

Comment: @xbh How did you manage to infer that?

Comment: There is an exercise to show that there are some uniformly convergent series cannot be tested by Weierstrass M test. Seems like this one. Maybe i have remembered wrong. If not correct, i will scrap this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x(1-x)^{n-1}$ converges for $0 \le x <2$ !!
2. Show that  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x(1-x)^{n-1}=1$ for all $x \in (0,2)$.
3. Let $s_N(x):=\sum_{n=1}^N x(1-x)^{n-1}$  and show that $|s_N(x)-1|=|1-x|^N$.
4. Let $x_N:=1-\frac{1}{2^{1/N}}$ and show that $|s_N(x_N)-1| =1/2$ for all $N$.
5. Conclude from 4. that the series does not converge uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x(1-x)^{n-1}$  for $x \in [0,2)$. Then

$f(x)=1$ if $x \in (0,2)$ and $f(0)=0$. Hence $f$ is not continuous on $[0,2)$. Therefore the series  does not converge uniformly.